# File query contentschanged event not fired

Tags: javascript, file-io, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I have a background task that tries to track changes in a local folder using the 'contentschanged' event, for some reason, most of the time the event doesn't fire.

**Some points:**

- It seems that in development mode the problem is less common or even disappears, maybe related to adding break points.
- The event is not fired when a file is added nor when one is deleted.
- I added the famous *fileQuery.getFilesAsync();* after adding the event listener.

Comment: Are you doing this with the app in the background? The app in the background will be suspended and won't get called. In development - e.g. F5 - the app will run in the background.

Comment: @DominicHopton Are you saying that if I listen to an event in a background task, there is a chance that the background task will ignore the event because it was suspended?

Comment: Your background task only gets certain time slices of CPU, and needs to be n the loc screen etc. the lock screen triggers don't include file system it looks like (I may have missed it), so it's quite likely your task is being suspended. Kick off a timer or something that executes constantly, and see I'd it gets to stay alive. I suspect your problems is that you are getting suspended.

Comment: @DominicHopton I don't understand why my background task needs to be a lock screen background task.

Comment: Because a background task isn't 'running' all the time. Only lock screen apps apps get to pretty much run all the time.